# Setup CORS in NodeJS to block requests from CURL, Postman and any other non-browser requests

Tags: node.js, express

I am using express for my web application, in the backend I want to prevent requests from cURL, Postman and any other than from an allowed domain, or if not from a browser.

Currently this is my configuration using CORS middleware:

```
import express from "express";
import cors from "cors";
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(express.json());
const allowedOrigins = ["https://example.com"];
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: function (origin, callback) {
      if (!origin || allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
        callback(null, true);
      } else {
        callback(new Error("Not allowed by CORS"));
      }
    },
    methods: ["POST"],
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
    credentials: true,
  })
);

app.post("/api1", async (req, res) => {
  //code
});

app.post("/api2", async (req, res) => {
  //code
});

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") {
  app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`);
  });
}
```

I want to know how can I make it more secure? In the case of cURL and postman could I implement maybe something that validates the useragent? Could you tell me how?

Answer (score -1):

You can't.

CLI tools don't enforce CORS, and the user of a CLI tool can send anything in a request's HTTP headers, including `Origin` and `User-Agent` headers that would make the request appear like it was sent by a browser.

The security of your server cannot depend on client-supplied data.